# SQL Finding all elements which does not belong to a particular set, in many to many relation

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I have problem with this task:

> Given are the relations
>
> Students: ST (S#, SNAME)
>
> Lecture: L (L#, LNAME, ECTS)
>
> Who attends what: LS (L#, S#)
>
> Find students (S# and SNAME) who do not attend any lecture having more
> than 4 ECTS

I know that I can do it by checking whether the MAX value of ECTS for given student is greater than 4, but as part of learning I want to do it differently. Namely I want to do it using subqueries:

```
SELECT S.[S#], SNAME
FROM ST
INNER JOIN LS ON LS.[S#] = S.[S#]
WHERE LS.[L#] /* and here is a problem, I want a statement like "none of LS.[L#] exists in" */ (SELECT [L#] FROM L WHERE ECTS > 4)
```

My idea is that `(SELECT [L#] FROM L WHERE ECTS > 4)` will return all of the Lectures for which ECTS is greater than 4, and then I just need to check whether there exist in this set one of those which are assigned to Student via LS table, and then skip it.

I know that there exist operator like  ALL and ANY, but it doesn't seem to work in any configuration.

I tried for example `WHERE NOT LS.[L#] = ANY (SELECT [L#] FROM L WHERE ECTS > 4)` but since it operates separetly per `LS.[L#]`, it just returned me students which have at least one Lecture with `ECTS <= 4`.

I figured out that `WHERE LS.[L#] = ANY (SELECT [L#] FROM L WHERE ECTS > 4)` gives me exactly negation of a set that I want - naivly I thought that NOT would invert this set - but aparently no - what I want is in this case would be `ALL STUDENTS - WHERE LS.[L#] = ANY (SELECT [L#] FROM L WHERE ECTS > 4)`.

Is there a neat solution to this problem, in this kind of manner?

Comment: As a rule, avoid `ANY/ALL =` as it's really confusing. It's usually clearer to write `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT [L#] FROM L WHERE ECTS > 4 AND LS.= [L#] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`, but the correct logic is:

```
SELECT S.[S#], s.SNAME
FROM S
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM LS JOIN
                       L
                       ON L.[L#] = LS.[L#]
                  WHERE LS.[S#] = S.[S#] AND L.ECTS > 4
                 ) ;
```

That is, you want to join in the subquery.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists` as follows:

```
SELECT S.[S#], SNAME
  FROM ST
  INNER JOIN LS ON LS.[S#] = S.[S#]
WHERE not exists
      (select 1 from L
        Where L.[L#] = LS.[L#]
          AND L.ECTS > 4)
```

Comment: This is not correct.  This will return students that attend *any* lecture that doesn't have more than 4 ECTs.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : that is what written in the question `Find students (S# and SNAME) who do not attend any lecture having more than 4 ECTS`

Comment: . . The question means "no lectures have more than 4 ECTs".  If English is not your first language, I can understand the confusion.

Comment: Yeap. But still I am confused. I know you are super senior than me but but I am able to map question and my answer still. Not exists lecture with more than 4 ECTS. This is what my query is doing. Pardon me if i am wrong @GordonLinoff

Comment: . . By putting the join outside the subquery, each lecture is being compared independently, rather than all of the lectures for a given student at the same time.

Comment: @Popeye Sorry for the confusion, maybe I phrased this question not exaclty precise (this is just copied from the teacher assigement), and English is not my primary language :/  Gordon Linoff is right - student cannot have ANY lectures which has more than 4ECTS - For example if student attends on lecurtes for ECTS scores look like this: (1, 3, 5, 2) then it should not be returned in this query because there exist lecure with ECTS > 4; namely this 5.
(1,2,3) TRUE
(1,5,2) FALSE
(5,6,7) FALSE
(1,5,8) FALSE

Comment: @sawyer, Have you tried the query from answer? Is it giving correct answer?

Comment: @Popeye Yes, I tried - it returns students who attends at least one lecture with ECTS <= 4 - and it's not exacly what I wanted - namely student must have ONLY lectures with ects <= 4, in your query for example this kind of lectures (10, 6, 1, 7) would pass, but it shouldn't, because as far I understand this query, NOT EXIST will now return true because of this (1). And I wanted "other way around" - when you have even one lecture > 4 - no matter what - you are ommited in this query. But thank you for your effort ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using a subquery that we shall name "Temp" that contains a list of students that *did* attend a lecture with more than 4 ECTS, we can select from Students that are not in that list with a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT
  ST.[S#],
  ST.SNAME
FROM ST
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT LS.[S#]
    FROM SL
    JOIN L
    ON SL.[L#] = L.[L#]
    WHERE L.ECTS > 4
  ) AS Temp
ON ST.[S#] = Temp.[S#]
WHERE Temp.[S#] IS NULL
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` usually optimizes worse than `NOT EXISTS`